# Powering electronics with a low-cost thermoelectric generator?

Tags: thermal, peltier

When I replaced my water heater, the installer was telling me how cool the Bradford White unit I got was because the electronics are powered by the same heat used to heat the water in the tank.  I thought it was a cool idea, but didn't give it much more thought after that, until now.

Are there good resources for designing circuits that can be powered with heat?  I couldn't find any information on Bradford White's website, but google turned up [this one article](http://inhabitat.com/mit-developing-body-heat-powered-electronics/) about how MIT is researching the use of body heat to power electronics.  I think it's pretty fascinating and would like to play with the concepts, if possible.  I assume that if MIT is currently working on it, then it's way past the ability of my pea brain to put something together, but hopefully someone here can prove me wrong.  :)

EDIT -- I should have thought of Peltiers immediately, but it just occurred to me.  I haven't ever tried applying a heat differential to one and measuring the voltage, but it's worth a shot.

EDIT -- I had to revise the title for this question.  I found a thermoelectric generator, and if its price is any indication, this technology is insanely expensive.  Does anyone know of an *inexpensive* way to implement powered circuits with a temperature differential?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to use heat energy for anything by itself; only heat differentials.  In the case of your water heater, it's the differential between the inside of the tank and the room that the tank is in.

Comment: @endolith for sure, I'm sorry if I implied that I was looking to use heat alone.  For something like running "Peltiers backward", I would have one end on the heat source, and the other at ambient, just like with my water heater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a development kit that looks interesting.  It includes everything needed to conduct thermoelectric generation experiments.

http://www.customthermoelectric.com/powergen.html

It's a little on the pricey side, so I'm going to keep looking for other options.  I wonder if I can just get the thermoelectric generator and pair it with a boost regulator to get a more useful voltage.

EDIT -- even the thermoelectric generator **alone** is way too pricey.  I think I need to reword my question.

Comment: I remember stories of [soviet radios](http://thisbluemarble.com/showthread.php?t=35990) which were heat powered and were supposed to be cheap for the time. Maybe some more research is needed? I know that you can get some power using thermocouples, but from what I can see, it's too little.

Comment: TEC's are not that expensive, especially in bulk. You can buy TEC's off ebay for very cheap just to expirament with them, http://computers.shop.ebay.com/i.html?_nkw=peltier&_sacat=80149&_odkw=&_osacat=80149&_trksid=p3286.c0.m270.l1313 like that. They are also known as peltiers.

Comment: Yeah, I did end up buying one on eBay and it was very cheap!  We'll have to see what sort of power it's good for...